# (Angular) error typeerror cannot read property 'date' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I'm new to Angular and got stuck on something. I'm trying to read a property from input and transfer it to a server that will put the data in the database but the object that comes to the server is null because of the following problem: `error typeerror cannot read property 'date' of undefined``

I guess the problem is in this line with `[(ngModel)]="Productivity.Date"`

This is probably a rookie mistake, I have already tried to test possible solutions but have not found an example that fits my problem.

IntroducingLaborProductivity.html

```
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <div class="input-group-desc">
                                <input [(ngModel)]="productivity.Date" class="input--style-5" id="input--style-5" type="date" name="date">                    
                                <label class="label--desc">date</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

IntroducingLaborProductivity.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Time } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/shared/services/user.service';
import { Productivity } from 'src/app/shared/models/productivity';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-introducing-labor-productivity',
  templateUrl: './introducing-labor-productivity.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./introducing-labor-productivity.component.css']
})
export class IntroducingLaborProductivityComponent implements OnInit {

productivity:Productivity;

  constructor(private router:Router,private userservice:UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  
 InsertProductivity(){
   this.userservice.InsertProductivity(this.productivity).subscribe(
     res=>{
       if(res)
       alert("succsful")
     },
     err=>(alert("faild"))
   )
    
 }
}
```

Productivity.ts (the model)

```
import { Time } from '@angular/common'

export class Productivity {
    ProductivyCode:number
    UserCode: number
    ProductivityNum: number
    Cmment:string
    Date:Date
    DurationOfPreparation:Time
    ProductivityStatus:number
}
```

user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from '../models/user.model';
import { Productivity } from '../models/productivity';
import { Time } from '@angular/common';
//import { read } from 'fs';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  url: string = "https://localhost:44387/api/User/";
  user: User;
  isLoggedIn: boolean;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  InsertProductivity ( prod:Productivity) {
  return this.http.post(this.url + 'productivity',prod) ;
 }
}
```

Comment: `this.productivity` is initially `undefined` and *never* actually set, it's unclear where you expected a value to come from.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, I am trying to put some value into the input and absorb it into the above variable

Comment: But you're trying to set `productivity.Date` when `productivity` can never be anything other than `undefined`, and `undefined.Date` is indeed a type error. You need some initial value, even if it's just an empty object `{}`. Note that having a class without any methods or accessor is fairly pointless, just use an interface for the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially `this.productivity` is undefined, when trying to access the member date it'll raise an error and break the binding for it to prevent multiple errors.

you need to give `this.productivity` an initial value like this

```
export class IntroducingLaborProductivityComponent implements OnInit {

productivity:Productivity = new Productivity();

.
.
.
```